# Visual Studio PyTools Create Django project from existing code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I'm working on some django project. Previously i've been using Visual Studio Code, but now I would like to switch to Visual Studio 2015 with pytools.
What I've done so far

1. Clone my git repository
2. Create new python project From existing python code (There was no 'create django project from existing python code..)
3. The project was created, all files are imported
4. When I was trying to run project I've received multiple-missing-packages errors. I used Python.InstallPackage and installed all packages from requirements.txt.
5. I've set Project->properties->Debug->Launch mode to 'Django Web Lanucher' and set Run Server Command  and Debug server command (i'v copied them from clear djang project - i don't know if it's okay..)
6. When i right click the project and expand the menu 'Python' I've got only 'Run PyLint'. In Clear project there are many options..
7. Now when I start project I can see only a windows command window with information

> Type 'manage.py help < subcommand >' for help on a specific subcommand
>
> Available subcommands:
>
> [auth]
>
> etc

When I create a clear, new django project and click run it opens Google Chrome with django template site (even on the running button there is 'Google Chrome' text).
In my created-from-existing-code project there is only 'Start' text.

What should I to to make my created-from-existing-code-project act like clear django project (it sould run postgresql server and Google chrome)?

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to get this to work for close to 3 hours now, and I have not been able to figure it out. I believe that the problem lies in the fact that the "import from existing code" option for Python does not recognize that this is a Django project, but instead only sees it as a Python project. VS is running manage.py as if it were a full Python program, but Django expects there to be arguments passed to the program to do more with it. When you start a new Django project VS does all this automatically for you and it makes working in it much easier.

I have given up on figuring out how to do this natively, although I may put in a request with the Devs of Python Tools for Visual Studio to see if this could be included in a future release. For now, I am just going to recreate the code in a new Django project so I can get working on it.

If anyone is able to find a better solution for this, I would definitely be interested, as I realize this isn't much of an answer. If I hear back from the Devs at Python Tools, I will update this post.

--Edit--
It seems that the devs are already aware of this. This can be found here.
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/2036

I have found a workaround by redefining the properties of the project. For me, I changed the Launch mode to "Django Web launcher", changed the script arguments to "runserver" and changed the port number to "8000". Now, I believe that there will still be issues with the other commands available by default (makemigrations, createsuperuser, etc.), but this will at least let your server get run and open in your default browser when the project is run.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't realize that I would be able to comment later, I thought that I could only reply through the "Answer" button. I can remove this if you think it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem while trying to use an existing Django project in Visual Studio Community 2017. To make it work I had to manually edit the project's "projectname.pyproj" file (with any text editor).

To get the django tools to show up in the project menu, I had to disable the general Python tools and replace them with the Django-specific tools (this was near the end of the file for me):

```
<!-- <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.targets" /> -->

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets" />
```

After doing this and setting up the environment properly (making sure the paths are right) it started working for me.